# Concurrency in C++ with Boost

Tags: c++, concurrency

I have a very simple function in C++:

```
double testSpeed()
{
    using namespace boost;
    int temp = 0;

    timer aTimer; 
    //1 billion iterations.  
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        temp = temp + i;
    }
    double elapsedSec =  aTimer.elapsed();
    double speed = 1.0/elapsedSec;

    return speed;
}
```

I want to run this function with multiple threads. I saw examples online that I can
do it as follows:

```
 // start two new threads that calls the "hello_world" function
  boost::thread my_thread1(&testSpeed);
  boost::thread my_thread2(&testSpeed);

  // wait for both threads to finish
  my_thread1.join();
  my_thread2.join();
```

However, this will run two threads that each will iterate billion times, right? I want the
two threads to do the job concurrently so the entire thing will run faster. I don't care
about sync, it's just a speed test.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to sync if you want to share data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a nicer way, but this should work, it passes the range of variable to iterate over into the thread, it also starts a single timer before the threads are started, and ends after the timer after they're both done. It should be pretty obvious how to scale this up to more threads.

```
void testSpeed(int start, int end)
{
  int temp = 0;
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
  {
    temp = temp + i;
  }
}  


using namespace boost;

timer aTimer;

// start two new threads that calls the "hello_world" function

boost::thread my_thread1(&testSpeed,         0,  500000000);
boost::thread my_thread2(&testSpeed, 500000000, 1000000000);

// wait for both threads to finish
my_thread1.join();
my_thread2.join();

double elapsedSec =  aTimer.elapsed();
double speed = 1.0/elapsedSec;
```